# Extract characters between a string and the first occurrence of something in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to extract a set of characters between "u1=" and the first semi-colon using a regex. For instance, given the following string: `id=1w54;name=nick;u1=blue;u2=male;u3=ohio;u5=`

The desired regex output should be just `blue`.

I tested `(?<=u1=)[^;]*` on https://regex101.com and it works. However, when I run this in BigQuery, using `regexp_extract(string, '(?<=u1=)[^;]*')` , I get an error that reads "Cannot parse regular expression: invalid perl operator: (?<"

I'm confused why this isn't working in BQ. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `regexp_extract()` like this:

```
regexp_extract(string, 'u1=([^;]+)')
```